# How to get a proper tag Url

Tags: routes, tags

I use the code "Link to the Tag URLs" from the following article:
https://craftcms.com/support/tag-urls

```
{% if entry.tags | length %}
<h3>This entry is tagged with:</h3>

<ul>
    {% for tag in entry.tags %}
        <li><a href="{{ siteUrl }}tags/{{ tag.title | url_encode }}">{{ tag.title }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>{% endif %}
```

One thing is that the "url_encode" doesnt really apply as if I expected. The URL looks like this:
http://domain.dev/tags/My%20Tag%20Name

But when I click on it, there are still spaces in the address line.

So my question is: is that ok like this?

I was also thinking about using the kebab filter. There I receive this url:
http://domain.dev/tags/my-tag-name

which looks prettier. But I now I get an error with the routing when I want fetch the tag:

```
{% set tag = craft.tags.title(tag).first() %}
```

Comment: Possible dupes? https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/10344/how-can-i-use-tag-slugs-in-urls and https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/18277/best-method-to-handle-20-in-tag-urls-with-multiple-words and https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/6581/problem-with-accents-in-tags-url ?

Comment: Yes, definitly. But another post helped me: https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/17026/use-of-tag-slug-instead-of-tag-title-in-a-custom-route Thanks anyway Brad!

Comment: Awesome... would you mind adding what worked for you as an official answer?

Comment: If you look towards the bottom of this page, you should see a "Your Answer" section followed by a big WYSIWIG editor where you can add an answer.

Comment: yes, I know that but stackexchange always marks my entry as "trivial answer" and moves it here in the comment section.

Comment: Oh... I think maybe they're looking for a certain answer length? i.e. over X characters long or something?

Answer (score 1):

This post helped me with my issue with a different approach (except of using the kebab filter the slug of the tag is used for the route)

[Use of tag.slug instead of tag.title in a custom route](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/17026/use-of-tag-slug-instead-of-tag-title-in-a-custom-route)

as I think that makes lot more sense then using the title, maybe it would be a good idea to update the article in the support section of the craftcms website.

Comment: +100 on updating the article in the support section. I think that article predates the existance of `tag.slug`